# Flask Blueprint Flasgger Example Not Rendering Properly

Tags: python, flask, openapi, flasgger

Can someone please help me solve this Flasgger issue [here](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/issues/581).

I'm trying to use the Flask Blueprint example with Flasgger and when I spin up the sample app on my end, I see the page, but I'm not able to see any documentation of the endpoints. See below screenshot

[image]